# how to translate the html5 placeholders dynamically

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, translate

I'm using angular-translate to translate the page content in to different languages.

```
<input  type ='text' placeholder = ' {username | translate}'>
```

This works fine when the page loads ..but it fails to translate when I use `$translate.uses('fr')` depending upon language dropdown changes.

Can any one kindly suggests the solution to translate the placeholders while the language changes dynamically ?

Comment: <input  type ='text' placeholder = ' {username | translate}'>

Comment: username must be a string, so you have: <input  type ='text' placeholder = "{'username' | translate}">

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Did you try:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'my.i18n.key' | translate }}" ng-model="myModel">
```

Comment: For me doesn't..<input name="login_form_email" type="email" placeholder="{{'login.default_email' | translate }}" required> not translating runtime

Comment: For me it is not working, the problem comes when you do it at runtime, not at start.

Comment: This approach is deprecated, see @armyofda12mnkeys' answer, there is a directive to translate the placeholder

Comment: That doesn't work on Internet explorer, the documentation is pretty clear about this point. When the interpolation is being proceed an error/crash will appear. You should use custom placeholder directive to handle it as you want

Comment: This answer is close, but technically it is a better practice to use `ng-attr-placeholder` as the attribute because then Angular can hold off on display the value until it is actually ready (after the translation). The jank when using the original `placeholder` attribute is usually so fast you can't see it, but it will be possible for a user to see the untranslated key for a moment if you do it like the posted answer.

Comment: The pipe 'translate' could not be found

Answer (score 32):

There is a directive in angular-translate to help with this.
See [this issue](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/874).

```
<input placeholder="Regular Placeholder" translate translate-attr-placeholder="text" translate-value-browser="{{app.browser}}">
```

Here is a preview of a working plunkr from that thread:
http://plnkr.co/edit/J4Ai71puzOaA0op7kDgo?p=preview

Comment: This is the best solution to translate the placeholder attribute.

Answer (score 5):

+ira 's solution works for me.

```
<input type ='text' placeholder = "{'USERNAME' | translate}">
```

where username is the key for the translation. So that translation JSON line might look like the following in Spanish

```
"USERNAME": "Nombre",
```

The two together puts Nombre as a placeholder inside the input box

Comment: it works but should be two curly braces

Answer (score 4):

I Use this method:

In **en.json**:

```
{
   "ENTER_TEXT": "{{label}} را وارد کنید",
   "DISCOUNT_CODE": "کد تخفیف"
}
```

In **template**:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{'ENTER_TEXT' | translate: {label: 'DISCOUNT_CODE' | translate} }}" >
```

Answer (score 3):

I used placeholder="{{ 'some_text' | translate }}"
instead of placeholder="{{ "some_text" | translate }}"
that worked for me